# Plotting a sum of 2 exponentials looks like... well nothing

Tags: exponential-function

I have been trying to plot a sum of 2 exponentials where one has positive and the other a negative exponent. I tried to plot this function:

$$
f(x) = 30e^{2x} + 3e^{-2x}
$$

And i get nothing [here](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/) while WolframAlpha wont even draw this! Could anyone try in mathematica and post a good image here. Is it possible that exponential functions destroy one another?

---

**EDIT:**

I tried plotting this in gnuplot by using a script and nothing was drawn. Weird.

```
set terminal epslatex color colortext size 9cm,5cm
set size 1.5,1.0
set output "tuneliranje_1.tex"

set style line 1 linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#FF0055"
set style line 2 linetype 2 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#FF0055"
set style line 3 linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#2C397D"
set style line 4 linetype 2 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#2C397D"
set style line 5 linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#793715"
set style line 6 linetype 2 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#793715"
set style line 7 linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#b1b1b1"
set style line 8 linetype 3 linewidth 1 linecolor rgb "#b1b1b1"

set grid

set samples 1000

set key at graph 1, 1.0
set key samplen 2
set key spacing 2

f(x)=30*exp(2*x)+3*exp(-2*x)

set xtics ("$0$" 0)
set ytics ("$0$" 0)

set xrange [-4:4]
set yrange [-0.5:3]

plot f(x) ls 1 title "$f(x)=30 e^{2x}+3e^{-2x}$"
```

Comment: your need to set the y-range properly in the "function-graph" web site before you can see anything.

Comment: I don't know about WolframAlpha, but if you adjust the range of the $y$ axis on the page you link, then you can easily plot your function. Note that the default range is $[-5,5]$ for both $x$ and $y$, but an exponential function grows way too fast to fit in there...

Comment: Your `yrange` is way too small. Your script works as expected if you remove the line `set yrange [-0.5:3]`. By the way, you couldn't get a meaningful plot from the "function-graph" website for the same reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible that $30e^{2x}$ and $3e^{-2x}$ cancel out, since they are both positive everywhere on $\Bbb R$.

Here are a couple plots made with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for $x$ in $[-3,2]$ and $[-11,10]$ respectively

$\hskip 1 in$[image: plot between -3 and 2]

$\hskip 1 in$[image: plot between -11 and 10]

**Edit:** To plot, say, the second figure, and save the output to a png file, just open gnuplot in a terminal and type

```
 set terminal png
 set output '/path/to/output.png'
 plot [-11:10] 30*exp(2*x)+3*exp(-2*x)
```

Comment: Could you add the script that you used, because i like this a lot!

Comment: @71GA: Thanks! I hope this helps. If you don't like terminals, there should be a GUI version, too.

Comment: Gnuplot wont draw this for me... I dont know why. I used a script i put in an EDIT.

Comment: Well, you should at least edit the `'/path/to/output.png'` string... anyway, if you just use the line `plot [-11:10] 30*exp(2*x)+3*exp(-2*x)` it will plot to a new window, and not to a file.

Answer (score 2):

For $|x|$ large, one or the other of the two functions will be very close to zero.  Here is the syntax to get a representative plot in Wolfram Alpha: [plot 30*exp(2*x)+3*exp(-2*x) from -3 to 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+30%2aexp%282%2ax%29%2B3%2aexp%28-2%2ax%29+from+-3+to+2).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what is going wrong with your function, but you may be interested in the very similar and closely-related graph of the function defined by $$\cosh(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x}).$$ This is known as hyperbolic cosine (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) for more info), and you can see the graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cosh%28x%29).

Answer (score 0):

It is parameterised form of the function $f(t)=30t+\frac{3}{t}$ for $t>0$.